# PhantomJS execute script returns None in python Selenium headless testing

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am testing headless testing for one of my sample application with below code
Unable to upload file using send_keys, so actually trying to select elements on page using Javascript executing in PhantomJS web driver in python.

`driver.execute_script('document.querySelector("input[type=file]")')`

above code always returning `None` object in python. where as executing `document.querySelector("input[type=file]")` in browsers console resulting an input file type element.

Why am getting None type always in python with PhantomJS execute_script ?

Comment: `execute_script` doesn't return a value: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script

Comment: Thanks @Amber for your quick response.. it saved a lot time. Do u have any idea of how to upload a file using selenium web driver with phantomJS. tried a lot many options, no luck. using send_keys.. no response returning and halts at send_keys itself. Of course i logged an issue over StackOverFlow for the same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45188484/unable-to-upload-a-file-using-selenium-web-driver-phantomjs-and-python